# Why Fourier transform is not sufficient and we have to use Laplace transform?

Tags: laplace-transform, fourier-transform

Is there an easy way to explain the motivation behind the use of Laplace transform instead of Fourier transform?

Isn't that any periodic function can be represented by sines and cosines? Why to introduce exponential idea? Why not using differential equations with Fourier transform?

Comment: No, not every periodic function can be represented as a combination of sines and cosines. It is enough to consider some periodic but wild-discontinuous function.

Comment: And even for more regular functions, we may have such a representation, but without pointwise convergence ensured.

Comment: Anyway, the Laplace transform can be interpreted as a "rotated" Fourier transform. Depending on the functions we are manipulating, one transform or the other may be more effective.

Comment: A similar question to yours may be *why Taylor series are not sufficient and we have to use the Fourier transform?*. Well, actually we are not compelled to use one tool or the other, but the more tools, the better, don't you think?